# Where does this variable come from?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I saw this example from a book.

What I don't understand is where this interval variable come from?

It's not defined inside the data block and you can't just create a variable by assigning the value to it.

Is it a global variable in javascript?

```js
const POMODORO_STATES = {
  WORK: 'work',
  REST: 'rest'
};
const STATES = {
  STARTED: 'started',
  STOPPED: 'stopped',
  PAUSED: 'paused'
};
const WORKING_TIME_LENGTH_IN_MINUTES = 1;
const RESTING_TIME_LENGTH_IN_MINUTES = 5;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    state: STATES.STOPPED,
    minute: WORKING_TIME_LENGTH_IN_MINUTES,
    second: 0,
    pomodoroState: POMODORO_STATES.WORK,
    timestamp: 0
  },
  computed: {
    title: function () {
      return this.pomodoroState === POMODORO_STATES.WORK ? 'Work!' : 'Rest!'
    },
    min: function () {
      if (this.minute < 10) {
        return '0' + this.minute;
      }

      return this.minute;
    },
    sec: function () {
      if (this.second < 10) {
        return '0' + this.second;
      }

      return this.second;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    start: function () {
      this.state = STATES.STARTED;
      this._tick();
      this.interval = setInterval(this._tick, 1000);
    },
    pause: function () {
      this.state = STATES.PAUSED;
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    },
    stop: function () {
      this.state = STATES.STOPPED;
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.pomodoroState = POMODORO_STATES.WORK;
      this.minute = WORKING_TIME_LENGTH_IN_MINUTES;
      this.second = 0;
    },
    _tick: function () {
      //if second is not 0, just decrement second
      if (this.second !== 0) {
        this.second--;
        return;
      }
      //if second is 0 and minute is not 0, decrement minute and set second to 59
      if (this.minute !== 0) {
        this.minute--;
        this.second = 59;
        return;
      }
      //if second is 0 and minute is 0, toggle working/resting intervals
      this.pomodoroState = this.pomodoroState === POMODORO_STATES.WORK ? POMODORO_STATES.REST : POMODORO_STATES.WORK;
      if (this.pomodoroState === POMODORO_STATES.WORK) {
        this.minute = WORKING_TIME_LENGTH_IN_MINUTES;
      } else {
        this.minute = RESTING_TIME_LENGTH_IN_MINUTES;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
button:disabled i {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container">
  <h2>
    <span>Pomodoro</span>
    <button :disabled="state==='started'" title="start" @click="start()">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
    </button>
    <button :disabled="state!=='started'" title="pause" @click="pause()">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></i>
    </button>
    <button :disabled="state!=='started' && state !== 'paused'" title="stop" @click="stop()">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i>
    </button>
  </h2>
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  <div class="well">
    <div class="pomodoro-timer">
      <span>{{ min }}</span>:<span>{{ sec }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's exactly like `this.state`, `this.pomodoroState`, `this.minute`, `this.second` - which you don't seem to have a problem with!

Comment: @JaromandaX but those variables are already defined in data obj.

Comment: you need to understand working with objects(classes) and how `this` works

Answer (score 2):

`interval`variable is defined in `start` method

```
this.interval = setInterval(this._tick, 1000)
```

to hold the reference of setInterval so it can be cleared later in `pause` and `stop` methods. The thing which is confusing you is that why `interval` is not defined in state? If something is not defined in state, it does not mean you cannot attach it to vue instance (`this`) in any of the methods. You can do this legally in javascript and it is not related to Vue.

However author of this code should have declared `interval` in state like `interval: null` to avoid confusion and it is best practice also.